# Why won't my browser load what I've written in code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

For practice, I'm trying make to this page where it shows different YouTube videos using AngularJS 2.  I know what I've done is 100% right (or not) but nothing seems to appear on my browser other than `Loading...`.

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Config} from './config.service';
import {Video} from '.video';
import {PlayListComponent} from './playlist.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/app.component.html',
    directives: [PlayListComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
    mainHeading = Config.MAIN_HEADING;
    videos: Array<Video>;

    constructor() {
        this.videos = [
            new Video(1, "Final Fantasy 7", "jpZ47ppAGf0", "Gameplay of this game");
            new Video(1, "Kingdom Hearts", "7QFYcuzRHSI", "Kingdom Hearts movie");
        ]
    }
}
```

config.service.ts

```
export class Config {
    static MAIN_HEADING: string = "My favorite videos";
}
```

playlist.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'playlist',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/playlist.component.html'
})

export class PlayListComponent {

}
```

video.ts

```
 export class Video {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    videoCode: string;
    desc: string;

    constructor(id: number, title: string, videoCode: string, desc: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.videoCode = videoCode;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{ mainHeading }}</h1>
<playlist></playlist>
```

Error message in console:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/.video
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:771:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:365:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:263:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:431:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/.video as ".video" from http://localhost:3000/app/js/app.component.js
```

Comment: What does it say in the console? Is something going wrong - any error messages or warnings? How are you serving the app?

Comment: Please add your `AppModule`. Do you have `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` Have you checked if anything gets called like the constructor of `AppComponent`?

Comment: how does your index.html looks like? You have to add `<my-app></my-app>` to it

Comment: Please keep in mind that we are not mind readers. We cannot see your screen or know what you are experiencing. Copy any error messages (in the browser console) you receive and describe in detail the behavior that occurs.

Comment: `directives: [PlayListComponent]`   ?

Comment: @John I have that in my index.html already.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I read somewhere that I have to do something with the Module folder but I'm not sure what, it wasn't clear.

Comment: @Igor Apologies.  I will put the error on my post right now.

Comment: shouldn't it go 
`import {Video} from './video';` and not `'.video'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you forgot the `/` in the import in `app.component.ts`

```
import {Video} from './video';
```